# Find commands by partial name

Tags: shell, command-line, command

Is there a way to get a list of all commands that match a specific (case insensitive) pattern? So for example, I know the command (which *might* be an alias) I'm looking for contains "diag" or "Diag" but I'm not sure of the actual command.

I'm currently on Ubuntu with Bash but am asking specifically on this site because I'd love to learn of a way that's usable across various kinds of distros (e.g. I'll need this skill on CentOS and Manjaro later on too).

I've tried `man iag` hoping it would work the same as Powershell's `help iag` but that doesn't work.

I've tried my [Google-fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=find+command+by+partial+name) but that only seems to lead to explanations on how to find files by partial name of text inside files.

I've tried searching this SE site in various ways (e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+find+partial+command), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=+is%3Aq+command+partial+name)) but didn't find a duplicate of my question.

How do you find the exact name of a command if you can remember only part of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `compgen -c` to get a list of all commands, you can also use it like:

```
compgen -c dif
```

to get a list of all commands started with "dif".

Combine it with `grep` to get exactly what you are looking for:

```
compgen -c | grep -i diag
```

which looks for any commands containing "diag". use regex for more flexible searches:

```
compgen -c | grep -i ^diag   # started with diag
compgen -c | grep -i diag$   # ended to diag
```

You can also use `apropos` to find commands, it searches into the manual page names and descriptions.

Comment: Perfect! The first option was what I was asking for, but the second option is equally useful!

Comment: You can use `-a` for aliases, `-k` for keywords, etc...